# Are datagram pipes possible in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, pipe

I'm trying to write some IPC mechanism for my Linux daemon to talk to other processes. I have been looking at mainly pipes to do this since it is more reliable than sockets. But now I have the question of whether or not datagram connections are possible through pipes?

Currently I'm doing something like this (removed error handling for clarity):

```
mkfifo("path/to/named/pipe1", 0660);
int ret_fd = open("path/to/named/pipe1", O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
```

For the socket, I can do something like this:

```
sockaddr_un sock;
sock.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
sprintf(sock.sun_path, "path/to/named/pipe1");

unlink(sock.sun_path);
int ret_fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK | SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0); //maybe SOCK_SEQPACKET is better/more reliable
bind(ret_fd, (sockaddr*)(&sock), sizeof(sock));
```

To make it obvious, I'm mainly concerned about message boundaries to ensure I am getting full packets when getting signaled to read and reading it.

Comment: Unix domain sockets are reliable. What do you mean by pipes being more reliable than sockets?

Comment: Mostly just from reading and conversations I have been seeing this. I think it has to do with packet dropping and buffer size restrictions on sockets.

Comment: That might be the case over an actual network but on a local machine the sockets should be quite reliable. Also have you looked at using shared memory or other IPC solutions?

Comment: I did but it came down to using pipes or sockets for design purposes.

Comment: You should look into UNIX domain datagram sockets.

Comment: From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/7/unix): "as on most UNIX implementations, UNIX domain datagram sockets are always reliable and don't reorder datagrams"

Comment: Pipes are guaranteed to write up to `PIPE_BUF` bytes atomically.  You could construct datagram-like behavior around this by using a fixed "datagram" length <= `PIPE_BUF` so that `read` is guaranteed to return a single "packet".  Pipes *might* be very marginally faster than unix domain sockets which are marginally faster than IP sockets on a loopback interface (localhost).   An advantage of just plain IP sockets over unix sockets that you should consider is that they allow the use of libpcap/tcpdump/wireshark.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland I believe that pipes *are* UNIX domain sockets under the hood: at least I was told so 30-something years ago.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland "You could construct datagram-like behavior around this by using a fixed "datagram" length <= PIPE_BUF so that read is guaranteed to return a single "packet"" - it's not though; the write is atomic in the sense that it will the entire "packet" or nothing at all, but a single read could still see multiple packets or a partial packet, I believe.

Comment: @davmac I think that is correct and part of the problem, especially since the packets are not a consistent size. I think I might be barking up the wrong tree here...

Comment: @davmac - Linux `man 7 pipe` says:  *POSIX.1  says  that write(2)s of less than PIPE_BUF bytes must be atomic:* **the output data is written to the pipe as a contiguous sequence.**.  Emphasis added.  The following sentence clarifies what "atomic" means here:  *Writes of more than PIPE_BUF bytes may be nonatomic: the kernel may interleave the data with data written by other processes.*

Comment: @BrianMcFarland exactly - writes must be atomic. This means that part of one write will not be interrupted by another write that is performed concurrently by another process or thread, for example. It doesn't say anything about reads whatsoever. As I said before, a single read can still see the result of multiple writes.

Comment: @davmac / Chef Pharaoh - There are cases where you can pad out messages to a fixed size, say 512 bytes--the min `PIPE_BUF` size allowed, and then always `read()` 512 bytes.  Unix domain sockets do not share this restriction. You could `read()` into a 64kB buffer and only get 5 bytes if thats your packet length.

Comment: @davmac - If you `write(pipefd, buf, 512)` from multiple threads / processes to a pipe and then one reader does repeated `read(pipefd, buf, 512)` calls, each `read` will get a single message, but this only works with agreed upon fixed length "packets" *or* by performing multiple `read`s to get a length (but `write` must still be done with a single call).  Anyway - OP should probably just use a Unix socket and be done with it.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland ok, I see what you are saying. I missed the significance of "fixed datagram length" in your original comment. It also assumes a single reader, which is probably the usual case.

Comment: After some thought and all the comments, I'm probably going to just use sockets where appropriate. This was a great exercise, I really appreciate everyone's comments here.

Answer (score 1):

As Brian McFarland's comment notes, you can reliably transmit datagrams over a pipe by choosing a fixed datagram length (which must be less than `PIPE_BUF`). All writes of this length will be atomic, and all reads of this length will extract a single datagram from the pipe's buffer.

Also, the [man page for pipe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) says that you can use the `O_DIRECT` flag for a "packet mode" which ensures that a `write` of less than `PIPE_BUF` bytes is treated as a packet and a `read` operation will retrieve a single packet. It is not clear, however, whether this also applies to named fifos.

However:

> I have been looking at mainly pipes to do this since it is more reliable than sockets

This is not correct. Unix datagram sockets on Linux are reliable and preserve message order. They seem like the perfect fit, here.